# Inexpliccable Android activity resumption behaviour - activites restart instead of resuming under select circumstances

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm experiencing weird behaviour with my android activities in an app I'm working on. Sorry for the lengthy post, but I'm facing a very specific issue.

Essentially, when I pause the activities manually by using the hardware buttons to put the phone to sleep or tab out of the app, it will resume the activity as intended on Android 4.* devices, but the activities are restarted on Android 5.* devices.

What's *really* weird, however, is that the activities resume correctly in 5.* under one single condition. *Only* when I pause by bringing up the list of active apps and resume by pressing the app in the list again. When I pause by using the sleep, back or home button, the activities restart on resumption.

Frankly I'm baffled. I even wrote a separate small app just to test that the methods are called in the same and correct order. The method sequence for pausing and resuming is `onPause() -> onStop() -> onRestart() -> onStart() -> onResume()`, on both my Android 4.* and 5.* devices. This complies with how the method hierarchy is supposed to work in Android, so everything is in order on that front. It's also the same sequence regardless of which pausing trigger is used on both devices (sleep button, back button, home button, or app list button).

I have absolutely no idea why the app behaves differently based on which pause button is used on my 5.* device, when the method sequence is the same and correct in all cases.

I've googled and read documentation for hours on end and experimented with different solutions to similar issues, such as adding `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23"></uses-sdk>` to my manifest, and forcing `android:launchMode="singleTask"` on each of my activities in the manifest. I've also made sure that the developer setting to destroy activities when you leave them is disabled on both devices. All to no avail.

More specifically my 5.* device is a OnePlus 2 running Android 5.1.1, and my two 4.* phones are a Samsung Galaxy S2 running 4.1.2 and a Samsung Galaxy Grand I9082 running 4.2.2.

Here's a dump of my manifest, just in case:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    package="placeholder.package.namespace">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23"></uses-sdk>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:replace="android:icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".GameActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainMenu"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```